# Invalid signal parameter type: MouseEvent

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

If I try and use a `MouseEvent` as an arg in a QML defined signal, I get the following error on load:

> Invalid signal parameter type: MouseEvent

There is conflicting information in the Qt docs regarding this, in the [QML signal syntax documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#signal-attributes) it states that:

> The allowed parameter types are the same as those listed under Defining Property Attributes [...] any QML object type can be used as a property type.

Whilst in the [QML/C++ interaction documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html#connecting-to-qml-signals) it states that:

> When a QML object type is used as a signal parameter, the parameter should use var as the type

Setting the argument to use `var` does work, but this seems unnecessary according to the QML documentation.  There was a bug regarding this [in the distant past](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-14550) but it was apparently resolved in v5.0.0.  So I am doing something wrong, or is this a regression?

### Edit

A simple demonstration:

```
import QtQuick 2.3

Item {
    signal sig( MouseEvent mouse )
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some souce code?

Comment: @folibis There you go.

Comment: This is a regression bug, it has been reported here: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-41441

Answer (score -1):

Use `QtObject` instead

```
signal sig(QtObject mouse)
```

**Note:** This works because `QtObject` is plain `QObject` which is base of all Qt objects

Comment: As of Qt 5.12 this causes error "Could not convert argument 0 at", "incompatible arguments is dangerous and deprecated"

Comment: I already tested this with Qt 5.12.10 and works without any warning or error. What is wrong?